# Button command binding doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I created a new UserContol with a button inside. Iwanted to bind the button command to a dependancy property of the new user control like this.

```
<Grid>
 <Button Name="Button1" Command="{Binding Button1Command}" />
</Grid>
```

this is the DP on the containing UserControl:

```
public ICommand Button1Command
{
  get { return (ICommand)GetValue(Button1CommandProperty); }
  set { SetValue(Button1CommandProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty Button1CommandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Button1Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(BptCellTemplate), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
```

when i try to use it nothing happen when I press the button. It doesn't recognize the command. If I add an event it works. Like this:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty Button1CommandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Button1Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(BptCellTemplate), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnButton1CommandChanged));

private static void OnButton1CommandChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject,
                                              DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
  var bptCellTemplate = dependencyObject as BptCellTemplate;
  if (bptCellTemplate == null || !(args.NewValue is ICommand))
  {
    return;
  }
  (bptCellTemplate.DataContext as BptCellTemplateViewModel).Button1Command = (ICommand)args.NewValue;

}
```

Is there a way to bind it without an event? because it works with other button properties that i did the same way (`Visibility` for example)

Comment: Where did you set the value for Button1Command?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that your binding is not working because there is nothing that says the `Button1Command` property is a member of your `UserControl`.

You can confirm that this is the problem by looking in the Output window when debugging your program in Visual Studio.  You'll likely see binding errors that member `Button1Command` wasn't found.

The typical fix for this is to add a name attribute to your `UserControl`'s root element, such as `x:Name="root"` (you can choose your own name or use an existing one if you have it).  Then, change your binding to the command to reference the new name:

```
<Button Name="Button1" Command="{Binding Button1Command, ElementName=root}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need class implements ICommand interface.

   ```
   public class RelayCommand : ICommand
   {
       #region Fields

       readonly Action<object> _execute;
       readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

       #endregion // Fields

       #region Constructors

       /// <summary>
       /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
       public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
           : this(execute, null)
       {
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Creates a new command.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
       /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
       public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
       {
           if (execute == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

           _execute = execute;
           _canExecute = canExecute;
       }

       #endregion // Constructors

       #region ICommand Members

       [DebuggerStepThrough]
       public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
       {
           return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
       }

       public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
       {
           add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
           remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
       }

       public void Execute(object parameter)
       {
           _execute(parameter);
       }

       #endregion // ICommand Members
   }
   ```
2. Now there is binding very simple.
   Define Command in your DataContext (MVVM ...ect.)
   Don't remember setup DataContext ... for example DataContext = this; (this is your Window)

   ```
   RelayCommand _btnCommand;
   public ICommand Button1Command
   {
       get
       {
           if (_btnCommand == null)
           {
               _btnCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.ExecuteButton1(),
                   param => this.CanButton1());
           }
           return _btnCommand;
       }
   }

   public void ExecuteButton1()
   {
   }

   public bool CanButton1()
   {
       return true;
   }
   ```

That's it ...

Comment: It's worth noting that you can simply use `RoutedCommand` in most cases: you don't need to create your own `ICommand` class.